# Getting leak after doing two times the same action

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I have a plist and I obtain its information in a nsmutabledictionary.
When I call this method at first time, It's all right. But when I do the same at a second time,third time, and so on... I get a leak. The code is:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)obtainPlist{    
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) {
        return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

and I call this method from another class:

```
NSMutableDictionary *credenciales=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc ] initWithDictionary:[CredencialesFTP obtainPlist] ];
ajustesCredencialesTableViewController.nombre = [credenciales objectForKey:@"nombre"];
ajustesCredencialesTableViewController.password = [credenciales objectForKey:@"password"];
[credenciales release];
```

this is the dataFilePath code:

```
+(NSString *)dataFilePath{  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kCredenciales];
}
```

The leak is in the call to the method obtainPlist. I tried autorelease the nsmutabledictionary but It doesn't work, any ideas??
thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that you are leaking, and what? And code for dataFilePath, please.

Comment: Instruments is giving me the leak. I'll add the dataFilePath code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **what** object is leaking?

Instruments will tell you that;  exactly which object is leaking and what line of code it was allocated on.

Once you have that, then you should turn on "track reference counts" in the Allocations instrument and look at the sequence of retains/releases.

There isn't a leak in the code you have posted so far.  More likely than not, there is an instance variable that isn't being `release`d in `dealloc` **or** you are re-assigning a variable without first `release`ing the old value.

I.e.:

```
id foo = [Foo new];
foo = [Bar new]; // this leaks the Foo instance
foo = [Baz new]; // this leaks the Bar instance
```

---

When you turn on reference count recording, what is retaining and releasing the dictionary that is being leaked?

[image]

(You can also turn on "Only track active allocations" when tracking down leaks.)

---

Aha!  Now we are getting somewhere!

So, the leaked object is an `NSCFString`;  an `NSString` for all intents and purposes.

You have this line of code:

```
ajustesCredencialesTableViewController.password = [credenciales objectForKey:@"password"];
```

So, where are you `release`ing the string you assign to the `password` property?  Assuming your password property is defined as `retain` or `copy` (it should be `copy`), then you need to release it somewhere.

Note also that you should *never store passwords*.  Not ever.  Hash the password with a salt and store that instead.

Comment: The object that is leaking is the dictionary. Instruments says that it is leaking. But It occurs in other time, when I'm not calling this method

Comment: I tried with the allocations but I don't find where is the allocation that cause the leak. The resposible frame is an nsdictionary, but the leaked object is an nscfstring. If Iclick on the Stack trace, it bring me to the code I posted.

Comment: You are right!! it was in that nsstring. I didn't release it because it was called from another dictionary and if I release the nsstring the app crash. Finally I solved it deleting the nsstring and passing the information by other way. Now I'm not getting that leak...but I'm getting a leak when I launch the device (it doesn't occur in simulator), but it is different. This new leak from a generalBlock-16 and the track doesn't contain the code of my app. It only appears once, do you know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the leak occurs in `[self dataFilePath]` or you can try not to `alloc-init` your dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *credenciales = [CredencialesFTP obtainPlist];
ajustesCredencialesTableViewController.nombre = [credenciales objectForKey:@"nombre"];
ajustesCredencialesTableViewController.password = [credenciales objectForKey:@"password"];
```

//EDIT: so if the leak occurs in `obtainPlist` you can try both methods separate and see which exactly creates the leak.

first try

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)obtainPlist{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]];
    return nil;
}
```

and then

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)obtainPlist{
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
}
```

just for debugging and isolating the problem.

Comment: It seems he wants a retained instance (from the initWIthDictionary). Try [[CredencialesFTP obtainPlist] retain];

Comment: I have tried retain it but it brings another leak, and I tried not alloc-init the dictionary but the problem doesn't resolve

Comment: I don't think he especially want it, because 3 lines below he release it again ;)

Comment: exactly. The weird is that the first time it doesn't give me a leak, it is the second time and so on when I obtain a leak

Comment: post edited. If both leaking you can try with only [self dataFilePath];

Comment: I tried tho options, the first one crash the app and the second one give me leak. I add [self dataFilePath] but it doesn't leak. So the leak is in the line: return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];

Comment: yep so could you try to return a non mutable dictionary, please? and I think the first crashed because you cannot set nombre and/or password to nil ;)

Comment: I tried to return a non mutable dictionary but I'm still getting the leak. I think that it is from another part because It appear when I touch in the textfield that contains the username/password. However, the code that I put here occured before. Is possible that Instruments detect a leak but it corresponds to another part?

Comment: Once you have identified that you have a leak & you know the object being leaked, there is **never** a need for such guess work.  The tools pretty much always give you everything you need to quite specifically identify the problem.

Comment: no I wouldn't generalize it. Sometimes Instruments give me a leak and point to a framework method or something else thats not in my project. But as I changed something that was not listed in Instruments the leak disappeared. I haven't remember what it was exactly but I think it was MapKit related.

Comment: I'm not able to solve the leak. I only know that Instruments tell me that the leak is in the dictionary, but it occurs in a different moment that when this object is called

Comment: @iPortable Yes, Instruments is showing you the line of code where the allocation that leaked occurred. *The actual leak may be because of an over-retain (or forgotten release) somewhere else*.  There is no need for this kind of guess work.

Comment: So, Instruments is showing the line of code where the allocation that leaked occured but you told me that there isn't a leak in the code I post, where is the leak?

Comment: **An allocation is not a leak**.  The line of code that Instruments identified *is the allocation that is leaking*.  The actual cause of the leak is somewhere else (in code that you haven't shown us).  See my answer for how to gather more clues as to where that is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this leak in the simulator or on an actual iOS device? One of the known inconsistencies between the two is that Instruments will report leaks on the simulator that are fine on the device.

The code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes I did, I proved it in simulator and device and the leak appears to both of it

Answer (score -2):

You should use this type of function declaration in this case:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)obtainPlist
```

instead of:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)obtainPlist
```

Comment: and it would be completely wrong, + marks a class method so that you can call it, without alloc-init the class

Comment: because of that I'm doing in that way with the +, I don't want alloc-init the class, only use the method

Comment: You didn't understand me, in case you use alloc/init mode you should use it as above, in other case you should use it with +